ThreadPoolExecutor scaling badly between from 6->62 threads
I have an application that needs to define and execute about 3.9 billion units of work.  It does these in smallish batches of anywhere from 1000 to 100,000 units of work (mostly on the smaller end of that scale).  I has to batch them up because each batch must be evaluated and that evaluation influences the inputs for the next batch.
The problem is that I'm trying to run the work of evaluating each unit of work in threaded code, for throughput/performance reasons.  It scales well in the beginning, but on larger servers, it scales negatively.  Details below.
I have a ThreadPoolExecutor which I am building thusly:
    // Leave 2 CPUs unused for system processing, minimum of 1.
    numOfCores = Math.max(1, numOfCores - 2);
    this.backgroundExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            /* coreSize */ numOfCores, 
            /* maximumPoolSize */ numOfCores, 
            /* keepAliveTime */ 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            /* workQueue */ new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), 
            threadFactory);

The application main thread puts work into the queue in small bits, maybe between 1000 and 100,000 requests, using this method:
public void addRequest(R taskRequest) {
    this.taskList.add(() -> {
        // This is a callable - so it's code that will run in the background thread.
        final ThreadedBuilderThread<T> currentThread = (ThreadedBuilderThread<T>) Thread.currentThread();
        T newObject = taskRequest.build();
        if (taskRequest.isBestOnlyMode() && newObject.getValue() > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
            T bestObject = currentThread.bestObjectReference.getPlain();
            if (bestObject == null || newObject.getValue() > bestObject.getValue()
                    || (newObject.getValue() == bestObject.getValue() && newObject.getId() < bestObject.getId())) {
                currentThread.bestObjectReference.setPlain(newObject);
            }
            // Don't return any object at this point, because we won't know which one is
            // best until all objects are built.
            return null;
        } else {
            // Not in "best only" mode, so return the object we just built.
            return newObject;
        }
    });
}

After each batch of requests is added, the main thread waits for the results, as follows:
public Collection<T> waitAndGetResults(boolean bestOnlyMode) {

    Collection<Future<T>> resultsFutureList;
    try {
        // NOTE: .invokeAll() waits for all the tasks to finish.
        resultsFutureList = this.backgroundExecutor.invokeAll(taskList); // , 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final Collection<T> allResultList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final Future<T> f : resultsFutureList) {
        final T t;
        try {
            t = f.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Background Thread was interrupted!", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Background Thread has encounted an uncaught exception!", e);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Background Thread has timed out!", e);
        }
        if (!bestOnlyMode) {
            allResultList.add(t);
        }
    }
    // Verify we got all of our work done (because we might have timed-out).
    if (!bestOnlyMode && allResultList.size() != taskList.size()) {
        throw new AssertionError(
                "Requested " + taskList.size() + " buildable objects, but only got " + allResultList.size() + ".");
    }

    // Clear the task list for the next group of tasks to be added later
    this.taskList.clear();

    if (!bestOnlyMode) {
        // We are not in best only mode, so return the full list of results
        for (ThreadedBuilderThread<T> th : threadList) {
            th.bestObjectReference.setRelease(null);
        }
        return allResultList;
    }

    // Otherwise, we are in best only mode
    double overallBestValue = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    T overallBestObject = null;

    // Iterate through the builder threads and get the best object built for each
    // one.
    for (final ThreadedBuilderThread<T> th : threadList) {
        final T threadBestObject = th.bestObjectReference.get();
        if (threadBestObject != null && threadBestObject.getValue() > overallBestValue) {
            // This thread had the best object (so far)
            overallBestValue = threadBestObject.getValue();
            overallBestObject = threadBestObject;
        }
    }

    final Collection<T> bestResultList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (overallBestObject != null) {
        bestResultList.add(overallBestObject);
    }

    // Clear the thread map for the next batch of tasks
    for (ThreadedBuilderThread<T> th : threadList) {
        th.bestObjectReference.setRelease(null);
    }

    return bestResultList;
}

PROBLEM
I am running this code on servers spun up on Amazon's AWS Cloud.  When I run on a 8 vCPU instance, I get better wall-clock runtime than when I run on a 4 vCPU instance.  But when I try to scale up to 64 vCPUs, the wall-clock runtime is almost 200% of the 8 vCPU runtime.
I went through my implementation and removed every source of thread contention that I could think of and got modest improvements, but the overall problem of negative scaling still persists.
Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can debug this or, even better, what possible source of contention there could be?

How long does each unit of work take? That you are submitting tens of thousands at a time suggests that it's not long.  If it's short enough then contention for the task queue may be costing you more than parallel execution gains.  The effects of contention for the queue would scale with the number of threads in the pool.

I haven't timed the amount of time per unit of work, but using aggregate statistics from a recent run, the average is on the order of 4 microseconds.  The problem is I've got 3.9 billion of them.

If you are correct, would that explain positive scaling from 4->8 vCPUs and negative scaling from 8->64?  Is there a better way to run such a workload in parallel?

I could try to make waitAndGetResults consolidate the taskList into larger tasks that each process, say, 100 units of work.  Do you think that'd show improvements?

4 microseconds is very short for a thread runtime. 3.9 billion is a ridiculous number of discrete tasks to perform in any reasonable amount of time.  "If you are correct, would that explain positive scaling from 4->8 vCPUs and negative scaling from 8->64?" Quite possibly.  At 8 vCPUs, you can feed all the threads efficiently as long as it takes less than 500 nanoseconds to dequeue a task.  At 64 vCPU, you need to be able to do it in 62 ns.  It's definitely plausible that the best you can actually do is somewhere between.

And yes, consolidating the tasks into larger units is likely to improve your performance for any number of vCPUs > 1, and it is also likely to reduce contention for the task queue.  I'd consider grouping them into units of 250 or more to get at least into the millisecond range.  And it would be worth testing larger aggregates, too.

If you suspect the Queue behind the thread pool is the problem, take a look at this https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/.  I am not affiliated, but used it on my project for a very large scaling message-based system where thread lock contention was a problem.

What kind of work is being done in your tasks? Is the work CPU-bound? Or does it involve blocking such as logging, database-access, file I/O, network access? While I’ve not studied your code carefully, at first glance it seems overwrought, and could be replaced with some simpler calls to an executor service using virtual threads in try-with-resources syntax.

@BasilBourque it's all CPU and memory.  No logging (except for exceptions), no database.

@JohnBollinger Batching the request and running on a 64 vCPU machine now runs in 20% of the time as the non-batched version.  I haven't done testing yet on different machine sizes to see yet whether it's scaling as well as it theoretically could, but it is MUCH better now, thanks to your guidance! If you want to post an answer, I'll upvote!  Thank you!!!

It is not free to dequeue a task from the thread pool's task queue, especially when there are multiple threads contending to do so.  3.9 billion discrete tasks incur that cost 3.9 billion times, which will have a noticeable impact for any number of threads and (v)CPUs if the dequeue time is a meaningful fraction of the task's inherent computational time.
Moreover, task dequeueing has to be serialized, so the dequeue time puts a cap on the number of threads that can dequeue a task per unit time.  Meanwhile, the number of threads that want to dequeue tasks per unit time is inversely proportional to the runtime of each task.  If the per-task runtime is very small, as in your case, then there will be a point where the number of threads wanting a task per unit time will exceed the rate at which they can dequeue tasks.  Additional vCPUs / threads cannot provide any positive speedup past that point, but they do still incur overhead, so your job overall may slow down.  If you go deep into that realm then it may slow down a lot.  This seems to be at least part of what you observed.
Consider some numbers:

you estimate that each of your tasks consumes 4 microseconds.

to serve 8 concurrent threads efficiently, that requires dequeues to take less than about 4 μs / 8 = 500 ns each.

to serve 64 concurrent threads efficiently, that requires dequeues to take less than about 63 ns each.

if your vCPUs are running at, say, 3 GHz then 63 ns is fewer than 200 CPU cycles, which is definitely small enough for concern.


It is entirely plausible that your minimum dequeue time falls somewhere in the vicinity of 500 ns, such that when you try to scale much beyond 8 vCPUs, you incur more costs than you gain benefits.
As a general rule, multithreading performance benefits from relatively coarse-grained workloads. A reasonable approach to that in your case would be to batch those 4 μs tasks into (much) larger groups.  I'd recommend shooting for large enough groups that each one gets into the millisecond time range at least, but this is something for you to test and tune.
Also, you may well find that that limits the number of vCPUs you can use effectively.  Do not overlook the possibility that you would be better off simply using fewer than 64.  If the cost of running your computation is also a factor for you then that's even more likely, because you need to expect the speedup per additional vCPU to be sublinear.
